# Want to install a HD on Lubuntu

Tags: hard-disk, lubuntu

It's a spare HD to be used to backup data and free some space on the one with the O/S. I got it from a friend who doesn't need it any more. I physically installed the drive and started up the computer.

The logical name is `/dev/sdb`. GParted says it configured as one `ext4` partition, but I don't know if it's reserved any for system. The existing drive with the O/S is `ext4`, if that helps.

The drive shows up under `320 GB Volume` in the File Manager, and the path is `/media/<my-name>/<random-uuid>`. There's an icon on my desktop with the UUID. It has about 160 GB of stuff on it: anime, cartoons, etc. I'm guessing the drive auto-mounted?

What I want to do:

- not have it show up as `320 GB Volume` in the File Manager
- have the path as `/backup` if possible
- format to get rid of all the stuff on it (JIC!)
- have the drive persist after reboot, i.e. don't need to manually set it up

I tried following some of the instructions on-line, but they are very poorly written, for example [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive) are really bad. Right away it asks a lot of questions and makes a lot of assumptions about the reader's skill level. It also looks like it has two different methods interleaved, and it isn't clear which steps go with which.

If anyone can provide some really clear instructions to get to where I have a clean single partition under `/backup`, would be really appreciated.

Comment: The uuid should not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fstab file for that !

> The fstab file can be used to define how disk partitions, various other block devices, or remote filesystems should be mounted into the filesystem.

Just add a line like this :
`UUID=<YOUR UUID> /backup ext4   defaults  0      2`

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab

Answer (score 1):

You can

- use gparted to add a label (name).
- edit `fstab` to make it permanently mounted where you want.
- use `rm` to remove files. (you will probably need `sudo rm`, as the owner will probably not be you. **Be careful**).